# Using the package RAdwords in an R script on a Unix server Error in rjson

Tags: r, unix, server, google-ads-api, rjson

I have the following script, which works perfectly fine, when I run it on my local PC:

```
library(RAdwords)

autX <- doAuth()          

data <- getData(clientCustomerId='xxx-xxx-xxxx',
                google_auth=autx
                )
```

However, when I try to run the very same script on my Unix-Server, then I get this error message:

```
Error in rjson::fromJSON(RCurl::postForm("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",  :
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'raw'
```

**Question**: What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

By the way:

1. I did copy the files `.gitgnore` and `.google.auth.RData` from the folder on my local PC, where I already did this authentification, to the directory on my server.
2. If I just type doAuth() alone I do *not* get an error message.

Comment: After which command does the error occur? Could you run the code in debug mode? What is the output of traceback?

Comment: Can you please run this code here line for line: https://github.com/jburkhardt/RAdwords/issues/90 Does the error still occur? If, yes after which line of code? Feel free to contribute in the github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue:

`getData()`calls the function `refreshToken()` that updates the authentication token of the Google AdWords API. Within the function `refreshToken` the RCurl command returns a raw data file instead of a character file format. `rjson::fromJSON` returns an error that is solved with the addition of `rawToChar()`.

## Solution:

I created a patch of the function and updated the Github development version of **RAdwords**.

You can install the new package version with:

```
require(devtools)
install_github('jburkhardt/RAdwords')
```